# How can I fix the .py error in kali linux?

Tags: python, kali-linux

trying to use kali linux to run my Phoneinfoga tool, but when I run the command needed to use this tool, which is

```
python3 phoneinfoga.py -n (the target number)
```

it gives me an error that says

```
python3: can't open file 'phoneinfoga.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do? Of course, I've installed python3 in my kali framework, but haven't been able to resolve this one problem, and the same error code shows up with all the rest of my kali tools, including Sherlock, and Routersploit.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Before executing `python3`, try executing `ls`. You will see the contents of the current directory. The file `phoneinfoga.py` must be in this directory, named exactly this way. If it's not, you can use the `cd` command to navigate to the directory where it resides. If you "installed" the `Phoneinfoga` tool in some manner, the installation may include another method of running it, such as executing `python3 -m phoneinfoga` from any directory. In any case, I recommend reading the documentation for the script.